# machine-readable submenu items

Tags: macos, applications, menu-bar

Can I get the text from a submenu in machine-readable form?
I guess I could try OCR on a screen-shot, but is there something better?

[image: JapaneseMenu]

You see, I have this program where some sub-menus come out in Japanese.  Now if I could get them in machine-readable form, I could try Google translate on them and see if I can figure them out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be about Apple hardware, software or services as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Here's a comma separated OCR, まばたき, 笑顔, なごみ,ウインク, ウインク右, ウィンク2, ウインク2右, although I think the third one didn't scan correctly. It translated as, Blink, Smile, Nagomi, Wink, Wink right, Wink 2, Wink 2 Right. You could use AppleScript to get the names of these menu items.

Comment: @user3439894 ... This particular one had only seven items, but sometimes I get 20 or 30 items

Comment: If the answer is "Accessibility Inspector which is part of the Xcode Developer Tools package" then I guess the question is about Apple software, right?

Comment: Although it's the only answer posted thus far, the answer is not exclusively to use Accessibility Inspector. Personally I'd try using AppleScript, which is part of the default macOS install and no need to download/install Xcode unless you want to. Had you provided which OS you're running and what app the screen shot is of, or the full menu from the menu bar to the "Eye" menu, I would have already posted the AppleScript code for it. The names of the menus and items are most likely just strings in various files within the application bundle and could be retrieved from there as well.

Comment: The text from a submenu is set by the developer, but ultimately provided using Apple APIs and the solution for this can likely be applied to any application. This would fall under Apple software (well, Apple frameworks really).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case You can use **Accessibility Inspector** which is part of the Xcode Developer Tools package (simply install Xcode).

To launch it use Spotlight (<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space bar</kbd>) and type "*Accessibility Inspector*". Then turn on inspection pointer with <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>space bar</kbd>, open your contextual menu, point on the item you want to inspect and press <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>space bar</kbd> to lock it again. You'll have all informations about element such as Title, Frame, Type etc. (you can copy paste them to translator if you want)

[image]